# Text overlapping font awesome icon- happened only in mobile/tablet devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-awesome

My website looks great on desktop. However, one of my form element - "Message" text is overlapping on my font awesome pencil icon when opening the form on mobile/tablet device.

Oddly, this error only showing up on tablet/mobile devices. It doesn't showing up in my responsive tools when I'm making sure everything looks fine on those devices.

I'm using Google Chrome responsive tool to test on these devices. I also tried to use Viewport Resizer at Desktop to test them, but neither of them pop up this issue on those sized screens.

I have added a photo to prove this and below is my code:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">



</head>
<body>

  <!--Homepage link-->   
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img class="avatar" src="images/Originals/avatar.jpg" alt>Mu&ntilde;oz Designs</a>

    <!--Toggle Button-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

      <!--Navbar links-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"
              href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"
              href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            </li>

            <!--Social Media Icons-->
                  <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/eddiearkmunoz/" title="Follow on Instagram" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/eddie-munoz-351a9428/" title="Follow on Linkedin" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/arkadiusart" title="Follow on Twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://eddiemunoz.deviantart.com/gallery/" title="Follow on Deviant Art" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-deviantart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.artstation.com/ed209" title="Follow on ArtStation" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php" title="Email">
                          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
                  <!--Intro of Contact-->

                  <div class="intro">
                    <h1>Contact</h1>
                    <h4>If you would like to work with me, send me a message!</h4>
                  </div>

                  <!--Contact Form-->

                  <div class="container">

                    <?php if ($msg !=''): ?>

                      <div class="alert <?php echo $msgClass; ?>"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 mx-offset-auto">
                        <div class="well well-sm">
                          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

                            <fieldset>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input id="fname" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $name : ''; ?>">
                                    <label for="fname" class="fa fa-user input-icon bigicon"></label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class=" col-md-8 mx-auto">
                                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $email : ''; ?>">
                                    <label for="email" class="fa fa-envelope-o input-icon bigicon"></label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class=" col-md-8 mx-auto">
                                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="3"><?php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? $message : ''; ?></textarea>
                                    <label for="message" class="fa fa-pencil input-icon bigicon"></label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                                  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-md">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </fieldset>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

<div class="copyright">&#169; Mu&ntilde;oz Designs</div>

                  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                </body>
                </html>


 html{
    box-sizing: border-box;}
    *,
    *: before, 
    *: after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    body{
     background-image: url();
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-position: bottom center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-size: cover;
     background-color: #464646;
     font-family:"Quicksand";
     font-size: 1.2em;
     line-height: 1.375em;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;

     background-color: #2F3A3B;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

   }
   navbar-brand{

    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -8px;

    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: -8px
  }


  .avatar{
    border-radius: 5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    margin-left: 1em;

  }
  .intro{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 65px 0 65px;

    background-color: #2A2332;
    background-size: cover;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;

  }

  h1{
    font-weight: medium;
    text-shadow:5px 5px 10px black;
    position: center;
  }



  .container{
    margin-top: 1em;

    margin-right: 1em;

  }


  .bigicon {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #808080;

  }

  .input-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: .5rem;
    top: .7rem;

    /* Keep icon in center of input, regardless of the input height */
  }

  .btn{
    margin-right:30%;
  }

  .input-icon {

   position: absolute;
   left: .5rem;
   top: .9rem;
 }

 #message {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.form-control {
  text-indent: 2rem;
  width: 75%;
}

.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;


}


.copyright{
  bottom: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: .5%;
  font-size: 65%;
}


@media all and (max-width: 1280px){
  .form-control{
    width: 95%;

  }
  .btn{
    margin-right: 5rem;

  }

@media all and (max-width: 1028px){

 .form-control{
  width: 100%; 
}

.btn{
  margin: auto;
}
}
/*Tablet*/

@media all and (max-width: 768px){


  .form-control{
    width: 100%;

  }
  .btn{
    margin:auto;
  }


}

/*mobile*/
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .form-control{
    width: 100%;

  }
  .btn {
    margin: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Try changing the `text-indent` to `padding-left`.
It seems that `text-indent` was a bug for mobile safari browser

Change it at here

```
.form-control {
  padding-left: 2rem; // change here
  width: 75%;
}
```

```css
 html{
    box-sizing: border-box;}
    *,
    *: before, 
    *: after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    body{
     background-image: url();
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-position: bottom center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-size: cover;
     background-color: #464646;
     font-family:"Quicksand";
     font-size: 1.2em;
     line-height: 1.375em;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;

     background-color: #2F3A3B;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

   }
   navbar-brand{

    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -8px;

    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: -8px
  }


  .avatar{
    border-radius: 5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    margin-left: 1em;

  }
  .intro{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 65px 0 65px;

    background-color: #2A2332;
    background-size: cover;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;

  }

  h1{
    font-weight: medium;
    text-shadow:5px 5px 10px black;
    position: center;
  }



  .container{
    margin-top: 1em;

    margin-right: 1em;

  }


  .bigicon {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #808080;

  }

  .input-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: .5rem;
    top: .7rem;

    /* Keep icon in center of input, regardless of the input height */
  }

  .btn{
    margin-right:30%;
  }

  .input-icon {

   position: absolute;
   left: .5rem;
   top: .9rem;
 }

 #message {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.form-control {
  padding-left: 2rem; // change here
  width: 75%;
}

.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;


}


.copyright{
  bottom: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: .5%;
  font-size: 65%;
}


@media all and (max-width: 1280px){
  .form-control{
    width: 95%;

  }
  .btn{
    margin-right: 5rem;

  }

@media all and (max-width: 1028px){

 .form-control{
  width: 100%; 
}

.btn{
  margin: auto;
}
}
/*Tablet*/

@media all and (max-width: 768px){


  .form-control{
    width: 100%;

  }
  .btn{
    margin:auto;
  }


}

/*mobile*/
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .form-control{
    width: 100%;

  }
  .btn {
    margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">



</head>
<body>

  <!--Homepage link-->   
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img class="avatar" src="images/Originals/avatar.jpg" alt>Mu&ntilde;oz Designs</a>

    <!--Toggle Button-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

      <!--Navbar links-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"
              href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"
              href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            </li>

            <!--Social Media Icons-->
                  <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/eddiearkmunoz/" title="Follow on Instagram" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/eddie-munoz-351a9428/" title="Follow on Linkedin" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/arkadiusart" title="Follow on Twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://eddiemunoz.deviantart.com/gallery/" title="Follow on Deviant Art" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-deviantart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.artstation.com/ed209" title="Follow on ArtStation" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php" title="Email">
                          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
                  <!--Intro of Contact-->

                  <div class="intro">
                    <h1>Contact</h1>
                    <h4>If you would like to work with me, send me a message!</h4>
                  </div>

                  <!--Contact Form-->

                  <div class="container">

                    <?php if ($msg !=''): ?>

                      <div class="alert <?php echo $msgClass; ?>"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 mx-offset-auto">
                        <div class="well well-sm">
                          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

                            <fieldset>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input id="fname" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $name : ''; ?>">
                                    <label for="fname" class="fa fa-user input-icon bigicon"></label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class=" col-md-8 mx-auto">
                                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $email : ''; ?>">
                                    <label for="email" class="fa fa-envelope-o input-icon bigicon"></label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class=" col-md-8 mx-auto">
                                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="3"><?php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? $message : ''; ?></textarea>
                                    <label for="message" class="fa fa-pencil input-icon bigicon"></label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                                  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-md">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </fieldset>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

<div class="copyright">&#169; Mu&ntilde;oz Designs</div>

                  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried on my iphone, ipad and another friends iphone- same thing. If you have an ipad/iphone you can try: www.eddiearkmunoz.com

Comment: @Alexandra found the issue. Try changing the text-indent to padding-left. I tried it on mobile and desktop. Both working fine when using padding-left

Comment: text-indent: padding-left; to only the the @media screens? or the parent?

Comment: Updated my answer.. Change it not in media, but at parent

Comment: That was it! Thanks! Looks perfect now! :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your CSS and doesn't see you reset it.
To reset the width, use below code.

```
.form-control {
  text-indent: ...rem;
  width: ...%;
}
```

for mobile screen at `@media (max-width: 768px)`. I think you should reset it to make it rendering properly.

Comment: I went ahead added that, didn't change. Is this common at all? Especially it not popping up on responsive tools?

Comment: You can try with adding @media (max-width: 768px) {.form-control {text-indent: ... rem;}} in contact.css file or find the other ways to overwrite .form-control for mobile screen

Comment: It doesn't an issue with what screen it is. But it was a issue with the browser itself